# SQL Server resources wait (Memory) very high and indicated server performance

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, sql-server-2012

I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

[image]

What can be a solution to checking or solving this problem ?
And can you guess should be the source of problem ?

Comment: Looks like you don't have enough RAM on the VM or you haven't capped what SQL Server can use and it's taken everything.  Otherwise, there is very little this image tells us about what's actually happening on your instance.

Comment: I think this should be at [DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).